# Calculate number of lines in a textarea with pre populated text

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I have some text in a `<p>` tag and a modal containing a `<textarea>`.
When the user clicks on the modal, I copy the text from the `<p>` into the textarea like so:

```js
$(function() {
  var temp = $('.messageContent p').text();
  $('#messageBox').val(temp);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messageContent">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in </p>
</div>
<textarea cols="50" rows='10' id="messageBox"></textarea>
<p><span>0</span> line</p>
```

After I copy the text, I want to determine how many lines of text are in the textarea. For this count, I need to include both explicit line breaks (i.e., pressing Enter) *as well as implicit breaks* caused by word wrapping.

My code will be functional when the `<span>` in the snippet above updates to show the number of lines written in the textarea.

Comment: look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501043/limit-number-of-lines-in-textarea-and-display-line-count-using-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit number of lines in textarea and Display line count using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501043/limit-number-of-lines-in-textarea-and-display-line-count-using-jquery)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *"continuous typing"*? Are you referring to how often the line count should update, or are you talking about *word wrap*?

Comment: @IronFlare - Continious typing means, when the user type something in text area and the line comes to the second or nth line.

Comment: @AhmedSunny, nothing works out in these examples.