# Php Validation for TextArea Number of Lines Limitation

Tags: php, jquery

I have this wonderful piece of code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556767/limiting-number-of-lines-in-textarea?rq=1)

But if some one edits the form through firebug or disable the js then this wont work, I want to have server side validation for this function, can anyone direct me to the right path please

Comment: And remember ALWAYS do serverside check for all user inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following php code will give you the number of new lines in the text data:

```
echo substr_count(nl2br($textdata), '<br />') + 1;
```

the use of `nl2br()` is to support the different new lines formats (\r\n, \n\r, \n y \r)

Test:

```
$textdata = 'First line
second line
third line
fourth line';

$lines = substr_count(nl2br($textdata), '<br />') + 1;
echo $lines; //will output 4
```

Comment: at the time of submitting the form, i need to validate the textarea input. For example, If a user has entered 10 lines data, then I need to accept else show the error output. Thanks for the info

Comment: But that is not server side validation!, you should do your server side validation on the PHP script receiving the form call, otherwise you are vulnerable.

Comment: hmm, I understand. Thanks and appreciate your help