# Limit rows on auto growing text area (Sencha Touch)

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have the following snippet of code for auto expanding the textarea in sencha touch. I need to cap it out at a set number of rows.

Any ideas?

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Q9gjN

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand your question on the right way. Do you mean http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Cq5Am ?

Comment: Actually this is close. i want to limit the number of lines that can be added all together. max rows = 5

Comment: Hmm sorry, i don't know how to do that :O

Comment: I would like to achieve this miracle as well.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be great if it were a nice, easy to use property.

At first I thought it would be the `maxRows` property but this is just the number of rows to display before the vertical scrollbar appears.

It may be that the only way would be a complicated solution such as this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/56392/How-to-Limit-the-Number-of-Lines-and-Characters-in

or

[Limiting number of lines in textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556767/limiting-number-of-lines-in-textarea?rq=1)

**EDIT:** I needed to cap the number of rows in an address to 5 lines.

One approach could be to listen to the `keyup` event on the `textareafield`, check for the 'Enter' key and then revert back to previous input.

The approach I have taken is just to add validation to the model, which works great.

```
{ type: 'format', field: 'Address', message: 'Address cannot be more than 5 lines.', matcher: /^([^\r\n]{0,50}(\r?\n|$)){5}$/ }
```

The regex restricts saving a record to the store that has more than 5 lines, of more than 50 chars.