# Limit the number of lines entered in ExtJS Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4.1, lodash

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/webfriend13/yZHnm/9/). How can we limit numbers of lines that is allowed to enter in ExtJS TextArea. Does ExtJs provides something out of the box or I have to reply on some cusotm function as shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556767/limiting-number-of-lines-in-textarea)

I am using ExtJs 4.1

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 60,
        layout: 'anchor',
        minHeight: 60,
        width: 200,
        items: [{

            grow: true,
            anchor: '100%',
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'textareafield'
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `maxLength` along with `enforceMaxLength` property:

```
Ext.onReady(function () {
    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
        height: 60,
        layout: 'anchor',
        minHeight: 60,
        width: 200,
        items: [{
            grow: true,
            anchor: '100%',
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'textareafield',
            maxLength: 5, // 5 is only used for demo purpose
            enforceMaxLength: true
        }]
    }).show();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZHnm/11/)**

Comment: It limits the number of characters that are allowed to enter but does not limits the numbers of lines that user is allow to enter.

Comment: Then you need to write a custom function.