# Restrict user input to fixed width and height contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, contenteditable

After a lot of research, I haven't found a post with exactly the same requirements so I thought write a new post.

I'm trying to create a fixed area (e.g. 200px by 300px) where the user can enter text input. He should be able to enter any character (including line breaks).

However, he should not be able to 'write outside the box' (i.e. there shouldn't be overflow scroll or hidden for the 200x300 area).

Once user reaches the 'bottom' of the area, they can't enter any more line breaks.

And once they reach the 'bottom right' corner of the 200x300 area, they shouldn't be able to enter any more characters at all.

Is this possible in css, angular, js, jquery, etc?

Comment: Seems like this could be done but you may want to rethink your requirements. Essentially you need to know dimensions of entered text, but this can become arbitrary if the user changes page zoom.

Comment: @DaneMacaulay, text and graphics zoom should be uniform, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, you are right @VallyN!

Answer (score 0):

Limit the length of characters with base in font and div's size, but you must change the font size and family or line height because every browser can have different styles.

To limit the length of characters in the div is need to ignore the HTML tags in the content, like interpreting.

Firstly calculate how many characters fits there.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the number of characters per line with the cols="" attribute and set the displayed the number of editable lines with the rows="" attribute. However limiting the number of rows could only be one with the maxlength attribute which would control the number of characters you can have, which you'd have to estimate. There are some [hacks to limit the number of rows with event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556767/limiting-number-of-lines-in-textarea), but they seem to have fairly major bugs.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, you just need to do following:

- Use event handlers to control character input process. It is required to be able to stop processing further keystrokes when limit is reached. Use `keypress` and `keydown`, first handles character processing, second - control keys processing.
- Each time user presses a key, use a separate buffer to produce final result, compute its bounding rectangle, and if it is bigger than limit, prevent event handling.
- Height of text body could be calculated by multiplying number of lines by line height (interpret `font-size` and `line-height` CSS properties).
- Width of text body could be computed rather easy with help of HTML5 `canvas` `measureText` method.
- If you don't have canvas, you can use offscreen `span` (or any other `inline`) element - just fill `innerHTML` with text block and use its `offsetWidth` attribute. Actually, if you replace line break characters with `<br>`, you may use `span` approach to get both dimensions in one go - just make sure it has same style as editable container.

ContentEditable containers, as i remember, store text body in HTML format already (in other words - with `<br>`s instead of line break characters).